# Is there something wrong with this chord?

Tags: theory, chords

[image: chord]

If you play this piece back, it seems this chord in particular has quite a noticeable timbre to it.

I'm just wondering if this chord is technically correct?

You can hear the chords here:
https://soundcloud.com/michaelscoop/chord-stab/s-UlqgnIrv8e5

**The notes under the chord**

Update, full track. Maybe it's another note clashing? Or too much timbre:
https://soundcloud.com/michaelscoop/track-with-chords/s-GRDUuCIruPZ

[image]

Comment: Weird, I didn't notice anything unusual about those chords when I listened to your clip. Are you concerned about the low bass or something else?

Comment: @Dekkadeci check updated question, I've added another soundcloud to hear the full track, maybe it's another note?

Comment: I think you might be using the word “timbre” differently from how I think of it. To me, the phrase “too much timbre” is very funny and also doesn’t really make sense. Timbre doesn’t come in amounts, at least from my point of view.

Comment: I am also interested to know what OP thinks "timbre" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks and sounds like a completely normal A major chord, just with the root note an octave lower than the rest. A, C#, E = A major triad chord.

The timbre of chords depends on the voicing and the instruments. Try transposing the whole sequence up or down step by step, and you'll discover slightly different timbres. Or try moving the higher voices up to different octaves. For example if you move the voice that goes E3 - D#3 - C#3 up a whole octave to E4 - D#4 - C#4. You could use that voicing for variety in the second verse.

Edit. In the second version, on top of the A major piano chord, where the piano part already had a moving or alternating voice (F# - G# - F# - G#) - you're playing a B note on a different instrument that also does a stepwise movement B - C#. The B note makes the chord momentarily "A add 9" or "A add 2". And that other instrument's voice moves as well.

Personally, I don't hear any of this as *clashes*, but because there is now more than one voice moving around, it gets a bit messy and uncontrolled.

Keep it simple. Think about things in terms of melody and chords. There can only be one melody that the listener keeps track of as the main plot, and harmony that accompanies it. If you use voices that jump and step around, make sure they aren't accidentally perceived as melodic motion. You can for example arpeggiate chords, which is kind of "movement" but if it steps along chord tones, the listener doesn't have to keep track of it in the same way.

It is possible to have truly independent *polyphonic* lines moving around along separate paths and with different rhythms, but it's an advanced trick, juggling with multiple independently moving objects. In *homophony* you tie your chord voices together so that they move as one big object.

Actually, I think there is an excellent and important question behind this, but those who have the problem, don't know enough to even put it down in words. If they could, they would know what the problem is and they would have already solved it.

What is the melody here? If you had to hum or whistle this without accompaniment, what would you hum or whistle? Keep that and present it in a simple way. If you notice you added something that made a mess and things get out of control, take the extra stuff away.

Comment: check updated question, I've added another soundcloud to hear the full track, maybe it's another note?

Comment: @Scoop Add all of the notes as text in the question. If you're asking "listen to my track and give feedback", then it's off topic.

Comment: Apologies, I've added the image with the notes underneath that chord. Thanks